# RBF versus standard classical analysis for empirical power functions

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, rbf-network

Sorry if the previous post caused any inconvenience to you. I am a newbie in Radial Basis Functions (RBF) and this is the first time I post a question.

I have 80 pairs of Y=body weight and X= body length of a species. Usually, the relationship between these variables is modeled as Y=a*X^b and classical or Bayesian statistics are applied to derive empirical values for a and b (and their associated errors). My question is: Can I use an RBF approach to derive a and b values for Y=aX^b ? To my understanding only predicted Y values may be derived from RBF. Please bear with me if this is a naïve question.

Comment: What is RBF? I googled it and, well, I assume that's not what you're talking about.

Comment: @Not when I [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=rbf+statistics&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) I consistently see what I expected: "radial basis function."

Comment: Try googling it without the word statistics. Regardless, it wouldn't be a horrible idea to define the acronym in this already low quality question.

Comment: @Not Why would I want to do that?  I would get all sorts of irrelevant hits :-).  Try hovering your mouse over the [tag:rbf-network] tag.  (I agree with your assessment of this question, though: I hope it will be improved soon.)

Comment: Look, when I hear RBF exactly one thing comes to mind. And it's not radial basis function. You've been around a little longer than me and know these somewhat obscure tags...